# get parameters in servlet always shows "null" when an ajax call is made .

Tags: ajax, servlets, call

```
enter code here

 Javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
var link="http://feeds.feedburner.com/techcrunch/startups";
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/FeedAction",
    data:"links="+link,
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error : function(errorData){

        alert("Some error occurred while processing the request");
    }
});
});
```

Below is the servlet where i'm trying to getparameters("links") which throws null all the time ,i'm trying to get the parameters from the "links" and set it in where clause to generate data from database .

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String url=request.getParameter("links");
    System.out.println(url);

   List<DataVO> users=new ArrayList<DataVO>();

    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedstatement=null;
    try {
        connection=ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("select description,date,link from post where feedlink in('"+url+"')");
        resultset=preparedstatement.executeQuery();

        while(resultset.next()){

            DataVO user=new DataVO();
            user.setDescription(resultset.getString("description"));
            user.setDate(resultset.getString("date"));
            user.setLink(resultset.getString("link"));
            users.add(user);

        }   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            preparedstatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            resultset.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    request.setAttribute("feed", users);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("FeedAction.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Not an answer, just some notes: (1) This should work; double check that the `url:` is correct; check with Firebug, what is the reply of the AJAX call? (2) Can you post the exception stack trace (and add line numbers to tyour code)? (3) Your code is open to SQL injection. Use `?` in the `PreparedStatement` instead of string conctenation (4) Close the connection and relevant resources (i.e. statements, result sets) in a `finally` clause (the code as it stands does *NOT* close the connection in the normal execution path).

Comment: You need to url encode the value of the var link.